# How to check if an event handler exist using jQuery or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, browser

I want to check if an event is available or not before binding a function to it.
The problem is that Google Chrome support the event "loadedmetadata" in the Video element while FireFox don't.

I did the following

```
$('video').bind('loadedmetadata', videoloaded);
videoloaded();
```

It worked well in Firefox but when I tried in Chrome, the function was executed twice (which is logical). I want to check if `loadedmetadata` event handler exists or not to run the function only one time in each browser.

If such possibility doesn't exist, any intelligent work around for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the `$video.data("events")` if this object contains your event, since you are using `.bind` all events of this element will be stored in this object.

```
var $video = $("#video");
var $ve = $video.data("events");

// checking if a `loadedmetadata` object exists in `data("events")`
if ($ve != null && typeof($ve.loadedmetadata) !== undefined)
{
    // has loadedmetadata event
}
```

**Full working [example on jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/WuEL4/1/)**

Comment: @Bruno - I'm slightly more confused now than when I started :(

Comment: @Peter: Assuming he is always using jQuery to bind events, it means all eventhandlers are stored on `element.data("events")`. It is an object that contains several objects, where those contains information about the event. e.g. event `x` on an element; the `element.data("events")` will return: `({x:[{handler:(function () {}), data:(void 0), namespace:"", type:"x", guid:31}]})`

Comment: Thanks Bruon, I'll have to look into this a little more.

Comment: It doesn't work, at least in FireFox, because even if the Event doesn't exist (not implemented by the browser) it'll get binded and added to that events object. So it'll give wrong results. I have figured out a way though, with the readyState property. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Omar: `loadmetadata` is not a standard event http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp . I though you were binding a custom event: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: it's *loadedmetadata* and not loadmetadata.  But isn't Chrome only implementing standard things?