# How to access the attached event handler in jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, onclick

I have a simple button in HTML like this:

```
<input type='button' id='btnPrint' value='Print' onclick="changeStylesheet();" />
```

This button already contains a onclick event handler. What I m trying to achieve here is to be able compose the onclick event handler for same the button. I would like to add second method that tracks how many times the button was hit.

**some approaches:**

First: Append another function call in HTML as per inline event registration.

```
<input type='button' id='btnPrint' value='Print' onclick='changeStylesheet();trackThis();>' />
```

This is the easiest way to go but not feasible in my situation.

Second: Grab the onclick event and check if it is undefined. Then, recompose the event handler with anonymous function using JavaScript native syntax.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('btnPrint');
var existingHandler = **elem.onclick ? elem.onclick : function () {};**
elem.onclick = function () {
     trackThis();
     existingHandler();
};
```

Third: Though above approaches work, I m curious to learn the way to do above #2 approach but with jQuery syntax.

```
 var elem = $('#btnPrint');
    var existingHandler = **elem.click ? elem.click : function () {};**
    elem.click(function () {
        trackThis();
        existingHandler()
    });
```

What is happening with #3 solution in mine is that I m getting
**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'trigger'**
error.

Any hints will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both handlers are to be attached in jQuery then simply set two click handlers. Internally, jQuery implements an "observer pattern" such that it aggregates handlers and will execute them sequentially in the order they were added.

```
$('#btnPrint').on('click', firstHandler);
$('#btnPrint').on('click', secondHandler);
```

These statements need not be consecutive or even in the same scope.

The same principle applies if a handler is already specified in the HTML. jQuery will simply execute any additional handlers after the original.

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='btnPrint' value='Print' onclick=".....;" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#btnPrint').on('click', secondHandler);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUCJ3/1/)

### EDIT ...

It is also possible to revere the order such that the original handler executes after a handler attached in jQuery :

```
var $btnPrint = $('#btnPrint');
var originalHandler = $btnPrint.get(0).onclick;
$btnPrint.get(0).onclick = null;

$btnPrint.on('click', secondHandler);
$btnPrint.on('click', originalHandler);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUCJ3/2/)

Comment: Thanks, this should solve the case where handlers added via script need to execute **after** the inline handler. 

There're some scenario like Submit button where I want second handler execute **before** the inline handler. That's why, I was looking for a way access the inline handler via script, assign it somewhere and then execute all handlers in any fashion (i.e. flexibility in order). 

Anyway, thank you so much for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right,

This should work,

```
$('#btnPrint').off("click", "**" ).on('click',function(){
     trackThis();
     existingHandler(); 
})
```

i.e. first `off` the existing event handlers , then `on` your custom one.

If this doesnt help you, this may be the one you want,

[How to check if an event handler exist using jQuery or JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898055/how-to-check-if-an-event-handler-exist-using-jquery-or-js)

**Edit**

If you want to override the inline `onclick`, you can use this dirty approach.

**jQuery code:**

```
$(function(){ 
        var mydiv = $('#mydiv');
        var inlineClick = mydiv.attr('onclick');

        mydiv.removeAttr('onclick').click(function(){
            // your code 
            alert('mycode');

            eval(inlineClick);

            // or first do, eval(inlineClick);
            //then your code later

        })
    });     
    function inlinefun(){
        alert('I am inline function'); 
    }
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id='mydiv' onclick='inlinefun();'>Mydiv</div>
```

**Without 'evil' eval**

(may not work in every situation, just gave a you direction)

```
$(function(){ 
        var mydiv = $('#mydiv');

            // Dirty way to get function name and its args by a string.
    var inlineClick = mydiv.attr('onclick').split('(');
    var funName = inlineClick[0];
            var args = inlineClick[1].replace(')','');


    mydiv.removeAttr('onclick').click(function(){
        // your code 
        alert('mycode');  

        // The default inline function
        window[funName](args);

        // you can change the order as you want

    })
});     
function inlinefun(msg){
            // I know I am passing string, so removing the quotes, you need a generalised approach here
    alert(msg.replace('"','')); 
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id='mydiv' onclick='inlinefun("I am inline function");'>Mydiv</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that existingHandler is defined at the HTML node (i.e. inline handler)..