# jQuery event gets triggered twice on mobile web

Tags: jquery, events, mobile, touch

Below are the events I have defined for my current view. I added the touchend to cater for access on the mobile phone

```
events:
  "click .join_in"      : "addMuse"
  "touchend .join_in"   : "addMuse"
  "touchend .promote"   : "promoteMuse"
  "click .promote"      : "promoteMuse"
```

However, I realize that when I tried to click on the 'join_in' button or 'promote' link, the methods seemed to be triggered twice.

Is this the correct way to bind the events for the mobile web? Do I need to define them differently or only bind them if I check that I am on a mobile?

Comment: If click event is called in mobile browser, just remove the touchend event. Else, you could define the right event depending on the device and browser type : http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/

Comment: So the touchend event and click event will cannot be used together?

Answer (score 0):

It should be depending on browser implementation.

You could test if the `click` event exist and declare `touchend` if not.

Check event exsistance like this : [How to check if an event handler exist using jQuery or JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898055/how-to-check-if-an-event-handler-exist-using-jquery-or-js)