# Edit OR Drag with same click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I want this: There is a div which I can click on or drag. If I click, I can instantly edit it (plugin makes it editable). OR, if I make a mousedown-mousemove event, it drags.

```
MY JSFIDDLE:
```

Here is my Code: http://jsfiddle.net/9N2hh/

The problem here is, that everything works just fine the first time. But the second time it somehow doesnt work even if I rebind the function.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

EDIT: 
I need the code to be like this:

```
obj.on('mousedown', function(){
    obj.on('mousemove')..  //here the drag should fire
    obj.on('mouseup') ..  //here the edit should fire (which fires without anything because "draggable: disabled" so just the mousemove need to be edited.
})
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using to make your div editable ?

Comment: Not clear what you want here. You are re-attaching the mousemove event every time the mousedown event fires. So after a few mousedowns lots of mousemoves will will cause the event to fire over and over. Do you want this.

Comment: Ye, this exactly is my problem. I dont want the event to fire multiple times. The plugin is like "medium editor", zenpen or pen editor. Its all the same, its basicly an editor which makes the div editable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/9N2hh/7/

```
obj.on('mousemove', function() {
    // Do stuff while moving.
});

obj.on('mouseout', function() {
    // sets draggable false
});
```

I'm using the mouseout event to reset the draggable attribute. I've also moved the mousemove binding so it's not rebound in every call to mousedown.

As I modified your code I wondered if a hover event would be more suitable? This would  indicate that your element can be dragged. You seem to be allowing drag when mouseover and mousedown, which is the default state behaviour of draggable.

If you really need to attach events in other events, you need to check if the event is already attached. Use this link [How to check if an event handler exist using jQuery or JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898055/how-to-check-if-an-event-handler-exist-using-jquery-or-js) is someone doing something similar

Comment: It doesnt work as I would like it to, what I need is the "MouseDown" event, and IN this event the "MouseMove" and "MouseUp" event. I have edited my main post so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Fiddle is unchanged I think. Nesting events as you have is unlikely to be useful you will attach a new event everytime you mousedown. Have amended my answer. Really wonder if you could just use a hover event?

Comment: Ye, but there must be a solution .. I think the only error in my jsfiddle is the reattaching of events, so the event fires 10000 times as you said (endless loop). I need to get rid of that

Comment: Edited for suggestion.